# Plot two pandas data frames side by side, each in subplot style

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot two pandas dataframes side by side, each plot should be in subplot form. I am using following lines:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create dummy pandas dataframes
pd1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(22),'b':np.random.random(22),'c':np.random.random(22)})
pd2 = pd.DataFrame({'J':np.random.random(22),'K':np.random.random(22),'P':np.random.random(22)})
#create subplot figure with having two side by side plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))
# plot first pandas frame in subplot style
pd1.plot(ax = axes[0],subplots=True) 
# plot second pandas frame in subplot style
pd2.plot(ax = axes[1],subplots=True)
```

Without subplot option, side by side plots are drawn but I want in subplot style. Is there any other option to get it done?

Precisely, I want to plot pandas in the following manner:
[image]

Comment: What is "subplot style"? Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question with a figure

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need a subplot grid of 3 rows and 2 columns to host your plot. Then the `ax` argument needs to take the 3 axes you want to plot the 3 dataframe columns to.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=2)
pd1.plot(ax = axes[:,0], subplots=True) 
pd2.plot(ax = axes[:,1], subplots=True)
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create dummy pandas dataframes
pd1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(22),'b':np.random.random(22),
                    'c':np.random.random(22)})
pd2 = pd.DataFrame({'J':np.random.random(22),'K':np.random.random(22),
                    'P':np.random.random(22)})
#create subplot figure with having two side by side plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))
# plot first pandas frame in subplot style
pd1.plot(ax = axes[:,0],subplots=True) 
# plot second pandas frame in subplot style
pd2.plot(ax = axes[:,1],subplots=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I still face a problem when the two data frames have a different number of columns. I think that is a different question and I need to find some workaround for that.

Comment: You need to create the subplot grid such that it can host the number of subplots created by the dataframe plot. Then make sure the list of axes supplied to `ax` has exactly the number of axes as there are columns to plot. Depending on the number of columns to plot you may not be able to use `plt.subplots` to create the grid, but rather create the subplots one by one or using a [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).