# Making multiple plots using two loops

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have this data: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/mushroom-classification.
I have split the dataframe by target column values, and trying to plot dataframes plots side by side to analyze the difference. I have used two for loops for each dataframe. this is my code:

```
edible = df[df['class']=='e']
poisonous = df[df['class']=='p']

for i in edible:
    fig = px.bar(x=df[i].value_counts().index, y=df[i].value_counts(), text= 
(df[i].value_counts()/len(df[i])*100),title=str(i)+' Edible Mushroom Distribution')
    fig.show()
    
for j in poisonous:
    fig = px.bar(x=df[j].value_counts().index, y=df[j].value_counts(), text=(df[j].value_counts()/len(df[i])*100),title=str(i)+' Poisonous Mushroom Distribution')
fig.show()
```

Code is successful in creating all the plots but there are two problems:

1. It takes two much time to show all plots
2. I need the columns to be side by side for analysis, I don't know how can i achieve that.

Can someone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Why not use subplots?

Comment: With subplots too i don't know how to plot the graphs side by side.

Comment: Check the example in official docs. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: Your [mre] should include example data - it can be fake data that you made up as long as it illustrates the *problem*. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You want edible[0] and poisonous[0] to be plotted side-by-side on the first row? Then edible[1] and poisonous[1] side-by-side in the next *row*? ...  Or like this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574378/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45574378/2823755)??

Comment: Does [Plot two pandas data frames side by side, each in subplot style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006699/plot-two-pandas-data-frames-side-by-side-each-in-subplot-style) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help really appreciate it.

Comment: Did one of those links solve your problem?

Comment: They didn't explain what i was looking for but seriously thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subplots in plotly are created by using 'make_subplots'. The first step is to determine the skeleton of the plural graph (the size of the matrix), and then specify the type of graph. After that, you can use your own code. You can also add titles and decorations by referring to the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/mixed-subplots/#mixed-subplot).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

edible = df[df['class']=='e']
poisonous = df[df['class']=='p']

fig = make_subplots(rows=len(edible.columns), # len(edible.columns)
                    cols=2,
                    column_widths=[0.5, 0.5],
                    specs=[[{'type':'bar'},{'type':'bar'}] for i in range(len(edible.columns))])

for i,col in enumerate(edible):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=edible[col].value_counts().index, y=edible[col].value_counts(), ), row=i+1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=poisonous[col].value_counts().index, y=poisonous[col].value_counts(), ), row=i+1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=2000)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Actually I did use the make.subplot but i was using two loops and didn't know how to assign rows and columns to each loop. Thank you soo much really appreciate your help.